# I need help comparing string lines from a text file in the resources to that of a textbox(vb.net)

Tags: database, vb.net, string, resources, compare

I have now found a solution to my previous questions but i now need more help.I want to compare a string from a user input to a list of strings found in a textfile.I succeeded that but now i want to do the same but instead of the text file being in the file system i want it to be in the application resources.I did find a way to read the resource text file and comfirmed it by making it output the contents in a messagebox but now when i substitute the normal stream reader code with that which reads the resource file the application sits there and does nothing instead of giving a message box confirming it found a string match like in the filestream code.Here is what i have for now:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Resources
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


'The original stream reader code bit that worked:Dim Lines As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("1.txt")

        Dim Lines As String = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_1")

'Above is the new resource reader code that is in place of old stream reader IO code


For Each line As String In Lines 'Every time the program reads a new line from the textfile database


 If line = TextBox1.Text Then'if a line from the text file 'matches that with the textbox input
                MsgBox("works")'user confirmation it matched
                GoTo A'jumps to "A:" to end the "for" loop
            Else

            End If
        Next
A:'where the jump leads to

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *For Each* statement effectively splits *lines* into single characters, not lines of text. You need to use something like:

```
Dim actualLines() As String = lines.Replace(vbCrLf, vbCr).Split(vbCr)
        For Each line As String In actualLines
...
```

Comment: Hi thanx for answering my question but I tried to substitute my code with yours but I still have the same result?Any suggestions

Comment: Put in a breakpoint and make sure lines contains what you think it does.

Comment: Hi I tried the breakpoints but it turns out that vb.net recognises the list differently in the filesystem than in the resources.In the file resources the list is recognised as one massive string while in the filesystem its recognised as individual lines each representing my strings is there.A way I could change this interpretation or atleast keep the file from being accessed by other people or programs?

Comment: Yes, GetObject () gives you everything at once, thats why I gave you the example of using String.Split, which gives you an array of strings, the same as ReadAllLines.

Comment: im sorry I really don't get this whole problem. Is it possible you could look at the project file itself and just see and correct where iv gone wrong in the code? then message me the corrected code?the project link is here:https://mega.co.nz/#!2hIUibIS!7EFHGjMJO37yqEV5f8nSWSPfkim5YcKw0z-gFhPRi78